# Python dictionary: Syntax error when using has_key and del in dictionary

Tags: python

I want to understand why the below code throws an error, I am trying to delete an item in a dictionary if a specific key is present.

```
    >>> 
    >>> a = {1:1, 2:2}
    >>> type(a)
    <type 'dict'>
    >>> a.has_key(1) and del a[1]
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.has_key(1) and del a[1]
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    >>>
```

The only way to make the above code work is to use

```
    if a.has_key(1): del a[1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`del` is a statement.  You can't use it as part of an expression.  It's not clear what you're trying to do with `a.has_key(1) and del a[1]` anyway.  Perhaps you mean:

```
if a.has_key(1):
    del a[1]
```

Or the alternative `a.pop(1, None)` which will also remove the 1 key from the dict.

Comment: Shouldn't you also use `in` instead of `has_key`?

Comment: Thanks, a.pop(1, None) seems to be the easier way to do it, just want one-liners to delete an item from a dictionary if it's present.

Comment: To add to Bren's answer - _any_ statement will give you the same error, its not something special with `del`. This `1 and print 'hello'` will result in the same `SyntaxError`.